How to run multiple dev containers with Clone Repository commands?
I'm struggling to make dev containers work with multiple containers. I have a monorepo with front (node), back (python), and I want to add a postgres database.
First try
I wanted to use a single container to put everything, but it's getting messy as I can't use official images for all services this way (for example, if I start from node image, then I need to install Python and PostgreSQL manually, which sucks).
Current try
That's why I want to split my local setup in 3 different services.

I followed this VS Code documentation for this.
My current starter code is here

But when running Clone Repository in container volume, this pop-up is displayed, letting me understand that no devcontainer.json is found:

It seems that a root devcontainer.json is expected, but I don't want to use one,  since there is none in the documentation example.
What's the right way to deal with this?
I know about this issue opened for 5 years and understand it's currently impossible to use a single VS Code window for all my containers.
But if i'm okay with opening two, one for the front-end, and one for the back-end, what is the right setup?
Note that I absolutely want to use Clone Repository in container volume command, and avoid bind mounts (awful performance, sync bugs, etc.) But examples often use bind mounts and this seem to  work differently.
Thanks for your help.

This seems to be a better start?:  https://github.com/gokhansengun/Simple-Mono-Postgres-Demo/blob/master/Docker/docker-compose.yml
